# matplotlib: change yaxis tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

For each tick label on the y axis, I would like to change:
`label -> 2^label`

I am plotting log-log data (base 2), but I would like the labels to show the original data values.

I know I can get the current y labels with 
`ylabels = plt.getp(plt.gca(), 'yticklabels')`

This gives me a list: `<a list of 9 Text yticklabel objects>`
each of which is a `<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x...>`

I looked at the documentation of the text objects at http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html
but I'm still not sure what the correct syntax is to change the string in each text label.

Once I change the labels, I could set them on the axis using:

`plt.setp(plt.gca(), 'yticklabels', ylabels)`

Comment: Did you use something like `loglog(x, y, basex=2, basey=2)`?  When I do that, the labels are already in the form 2^k.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser no, it's actually on a box plot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do this in a general case you can use `FuncFormatter` (see :
[matplotlib axis label format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775040/matplotlib-axis-label-format/14775453#14775453), [imshow: labels as any arbitrary function of the image indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645946/imshow-labels-as-any-function-of-the-image-indices/12654847#12654847). [Matplotlib set_major_formatter AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731879/matplotlib-set-major-formatter-attributeerror/14732779#14732779))

In you case the following should work:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mjrFormatter(x, pos):
    return "$2^{{{0}}}$".format(x)

def mjrFormatter_no_TeX(x, pos):
    return "2^{0}".format(x)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(mjrFormatter))
plt.draw()
```

The absured `{}` escaping is a consequence of the new-style string frommating

Comment: Running this, I get warnings that I don't know how to interpret:

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1242: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['STIXSizeOneSym'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1252: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=12. Returning /usr/share/fonts/thai-scalable/Waree-Oblique.ttf
  UserWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1242: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['STIXSizeThreeSym'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Comment: It looks like you are having issue with `TeX`.  See edit for non-TeX version.  You should open a new question if you can't get those sorted out.

Answer (score -1):

As per http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks

`a = plt.gca()

a. set_yticks(list_of_labels)`

Comment: using `set_yticks` is dangerous, because it decouples the tick labels from your data.  The text of the tick label is fixed, but the location of the ticks can change.