# What is the correct way to replace matplotlib tick labels with computed values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I have a figure with a log axis

[image]

and I would like to relabel the axis ticks with logs of the values, rather than the values themselves

[image]

The way I've accomplished this is with

```
plt.axes().set_xticklabels([math.log10(x) for x in plt.axes().get_xticks()])
```

but I wonder if there isn't a less convoluted way to do this.

What is the correct idiom for systematically relabeling ticks on `matplotlib` plots with values computed from the original tick values?

Comment: If you don't want to use `Formatter`, you could just use `plt.xticks(x_ticks, x_ticklabels)` to put the pre-defined `x_ticklabels` at each corresponding tick of pre-defined `x_ticks`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into the [`Formatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting) classes.  Unless you are putting text on your ticks you should almost never directly use `set_xticklabels` or `set_yticklabels`.  This completely de-couples your tick labels from you data.  If you adjust the view limits, the tick labels will remain the same.

In your case, a formatter already exists for this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(np.logspace(0, 5), np.logspace(0, 5)**2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterExponent())
```

[`matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterExponent` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterExponent)

In general you can use `FuncFormatter`.  For an example of how to use `FuncFomatter` see [matplotlib: change yaxis tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123928/matplotlib-change-yaxis-tick-labels/15124785#15124785) which one of many examples floating around SO.

A concise example for what you want, lifting exactly from JoeKington in the comments,:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
   FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:0.1f}'.format(log10(x))))
```

Comment: On a side note, `LogFormatterExponent` has a few quirks (e.g. switching to scientific notation for negative values).  It's a bit nicer to use `FuncFormatter` in this case.  For the OP's reference, `FuncFormatter` expects a function that takes two arguments: the value and its position.  For example: `FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:0.1f}'.format(log10(x)))`.

Comment: That formats the negative exponents in scientific notation rather than as integers. Also (more importantly) I'm curious about the idiom for *generally* relabeling ticks on `matplotlib` plots with values computed from the original tick values, not just the case where there's a `Formatter`.

Comment: @JoeKington huh, interesting.  I discovered `LogFormatterExponent` while answering this question.  You know the reason for that behavior for negatives?

Comment: @tcaswell - I'm not sure. I didn't realize it until after you posted your answer.  Just glancing at the code, it looks unintentional... Probably worth considering a bug and fixing (though I guess it technically breaks backward compatibility).    I may send in a pull request tonight, if that's alright.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me. I suspect no-one uses this code path, the formatter classes are not well publicized.

Comment: Meanwhile: what's the best *general* approach (where, for example, a `Formatter` does not exit for the task). I'm happy with answers that don't work in interactive mode too.

Comment: FuncFormatter which lets you change the number to a string any way you want.

Comment: Thanks, I see the edit. Accepted. Should I be noticing that this seems slower than my original hack?

Comment: How much slower? Don't know the exact code paths but I work would not guess there should be a huge difference.