# Change Y axis tick formatters in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I have a graph over

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

with values that are quite small:

```
[0.000001,0.000002,...]
```

When I plot this, it shows the y axis ticks with the whole decimal. I would like something like

```
[1e-6,2e-6...]
```

to pop up instead. How can I do that?

Comment: matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter has a scientific notation option: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=scalarformatter#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter

You can define a ScalarFormatter and use it to provide string representations of floats, which you then set as ticklabels, if you don't like what it does on the axes.

Comment: Or, possibly better for your purposes, a FuncFormatter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-replace-matplotlib-tick-labels-with-computed-values?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format) is probably what you are looking for:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

`plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))`

style sci for scientific notation, 
axis y to format y axis only, 
m,n to include all numbers for which scientific notation should be applied (0,0 for all)